# Font face In class and Id

Tags: html, class, css, fonts

Here's two Similaire code one using id and the other using class :
Css code {1} :

```
.section{ margin-bottom:25px; }
    .last{ margin-bottom:0px; }
    .section-name{  font-family: 'Sulphur' ; font-size:20px; padding-bottom:10px; color:#2F6AB3;  }
```

Html code {1} :

```
<h2 class="section-name">Personal Details</h2>
```

Css code {2} :

```
    .section{ margin-bottom:25px; }
    .last{ margin-bottom:0px; }
    #section-name{  font-family: 'Sulphur' ; font-size:20px; padding-bottom:10px; color:#2F6AB3;  }
```

html code {2} :

```
 <h2 id="section-name">Personal Details</h2>
```

In first Code {1} ,class, it didn't showed the right Font familly, "Sulphur".
But in the seconde Code {2} it Display the right font : "Sulphur".
So I need to know why ? for two reason, two improve my developping skills and because i here i want to use the class.

Comment: Is there any other code here we need to see?  Your second example had `section-name` referenced as an ID, while the first one is a CLASS. Do you have `<h2 id="section-name">Personal Details</h2>` anywhere?

Comment: Opps sorry just mistake it hase an ID

Comment: This is probably typo error or cascade from `.someclass h2 {font-family:"another font"}` or something else. Try to inspect element and find out witch css rules are applied.

Comment: i got this class h2 `ul.section-items li.item h2{ font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#272D36; }`. but i think it's not the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I test this code, it works fine for me :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .section{ margin-bottom:25px; }
        .last{ margin-bottom:0px; }

        .section-name{  font-family: 'Sulphur' ; font-size:50px; padding-bottom:10px; color:#2F6AB3;  }

        #section-name{  font-family: 'Sulphur' ; font-size:10px; padding-bottom:10px; color:#2F6AB3;  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="section-name">Personal Details</h2>
<h2 id="section-name">Personal Details</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

You should show us your complete code.

Comment: You probably have overrided the font-family rule. Use Developper tools from Google Chrome or whatever to track down the problem.

Comment: i'm trying now and i think it has confused with this `ul.section-items li.item h2{ font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#272D36; }`

Comment: I use default familly rule for hole project in body.

Comment: The css rule is the following :
the last applied rule has the priority. So, you have somewhere in your code after #section-name{font-family:'Sulfur';} , a rule that overrides your font-family rule.

Comment: @LibertPiouPiou That's not entirely true - the priority is calculated based on the number of classes, ids and tags in the rule.  Then by order.

Comment: @Dennis can you exmplain more?